# 来 vs 去 usage for the speakers movement towards a place

Tags: grammar, usage

So I know that 来 is used for actions that is moving towards the speaker and 去 is away from the speaker but I don’t know if I am moving towards a place I would use 来 or 去
For example: I go to Paris will be “我去巴黎” or ”我来巴黎”？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends where you are now. If you're not in Paris now, you'd have to 去 to get there, but if you are in Paris now, you can talk about when you 来'd or how often you 来. A lot like 'go' and 'come'.

Answer (score 1):

This question reminds me of this catch phrase: 点头yes, 摇头no; '**来**' 是 '**come**'， '**去**' 是 '**go**'; ... ...

So, I '**go**' to Paris will be “我'**去**'巴黎”.